# Nhibernate mapping class component of interface type

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

Last week I received the assignment to look for an alternative to the NHibernate hbm mapping, and decided to give the NHibernate mapping-by-code a try (seen that the fluent NHibernate project hasn't been updated in the last couple of years). Thank to [NOtherDev blog](http://notherdev.blogspot.ch/2012/01/nhibernates-mapping-by-code-first.html) and a lot of other questions here on SO, I was able to map almost everything, but I still have a couple of issues.

**Issue:**
I have an entity that as a Component of type IDocument, and it has a private implementation of this interface, but when I try to map the various properties of this component I get the error `Could not find property nor field XXX`, because in the interface this properties do not have the setter.

*Interface*

```
public interface IDocument : IObject
{
    byte[] DocumentData { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    DocumentFormats Format { get; }
}
```

*Entity class (to be mapped)*

```
public class ArchiveDocument : /* [...] */, IArchiveDocument
{
    private readonly MyDocument _document = new MyDocument();
    public IDocument Document
    {
        get { return _document; }
        set
        {
            ThrowExceptionIfReadonly(nameof(Document));

            _document.Format = value.Format;
            _document.Name = value.Name;
            _document.DocumentData = value.DocumentData;
        }
    }
    // private document implementation
    private class MyDocument : IDocument
    {
        public MyDocument(){ /* constructor */}
        private byte[] _documentData;
        public byte[] DocumentData
        {
            get { return _documentData; }
            set
            {
                _documentData = value;
            }
        }

        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        private DocumentFormats _format;
        public DocumentFormats Format
        {
            get { return _format; }
            set { _format = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

*Mapping*

```
public class ArchiveDocumentMap : ClassMapping<ArchiveDocument>
{
    Table("DOCUMENT");
    Lazy(false);
    OptimisticLock(OptimisticLockMode.Version);

    Component(d => d.Document, d =>
    {
        d.Access(Accessor.Field);
        d.Property(dd => dd.DocumentData, dd =>
        {
            dd.Column("DOC_B_DOCUMENT_DATA");
            dd.Access(Accessor.Field);
            dd.Type<BinaryBlobType>();
            dd.Insert(true);
            dd.Update(false);
        });
        d.Property(dd => dd.Format, dd =>
        {
            dd.Column("DOC_S_FORMAT");
            dd.Access(Accessor.Field);
            dd.Type<EnumStringType<DocumentFormats>>();
        });
        d.Property(dd => dd.Name, dd =>
        {
            dd.Column("DOC_S_NAME");
            dd.Access(Accessor.Field);
            dd.Type</*own type*/>();
         });
    });
}
```

*old hbm*

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="/*namespace of class*/" assembly="/*namespace of assebly*/.ArchiveDocument">
  <class name="ArchiveDocument" table="DOCUMENT" optimistic-lock="version" lazy="false">
    <component name="Document" access="field.camelcase-underscore">
      <property name="DocumentData" column="DOC_B_DOCUMENT_DATA" access="field.camelcase-underscore" type="BinaryBlob" insert="true" update="false"/>
      <property name="Format" column="DOC_S_FORMAT" access="field.camelcase-underscore" type="NHibernate.Type.EnumStringType`1[[/* Enum path */]], NHibernate"/>
      <property name="Name" column="DOC_S_NAME" access="field.camelcase-underscore" type="/* Own type (variant of string) */"/>
    </component>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

*Error*

```
Could not find property nor field 'DocumentData' in class '/* Namespace */.IDocument'
```

From what I understand both, mapping-by-code and Fluent NHibernate, are not "interface friendly", but in my opinion if the hbm file was able to map this class, so should mapping-by-code. Am I doing something wrong, or is there no way to do what I want with mapping-by-code? If the latter, is there a work around?

**Edit:**

The error is not `DocumentData` specific, If I comment it out, the same happens for `Name` and `Format`.

**Edit 2:** *Complete Stacktrace of inner exception*

```
[PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find property nor field 'DocumentData' in class 'Eis.Framework.Business.Core.Document.IDocument']
   NHibernate.Properties.FieldAccessor.GetField(Type type, String fieldName, Type originalType) +220
   NHibernate.Properties.FieldAccessor.GetField(Type type, String fieldName, Type originalType) +90
   NHibernate.Properties.FieldAccessor.GetGetter(Type theClass, String propertyName) +84
   NHibernate.Tuple.Component.PocoComponentTuplizer.BuildGetter(Component component, Property prop) +41
   NHibernate.Tuple.Component.AbstractComponentTuplizer..ctor(Component component) +168
   NHibernate.Tuple.Component.PocoComponentTuplizer..ctor(Component component) +21
   NHibernate.Tuple.Component.ComponentEntityModeToTuplizerMapping..ctor(Component component) +368
   NHibernate.Tuple.Component.ComponentMetamodel..ctor(Component component) +301
   NHibernate.Mapping.Component.BuildType() +28
   NHibernate.Mapping.Component.get_Type() +16
   NHibernate.Mapping.SimpleValue.IsValid(IMapping mapping) +30
   NHibernate.Mapping.PersistentClass.Validate(IMapping mapping) +87
   NHibernate.Mapping.RootClass.Validate(IMapping mapping) +35
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.ValidateEntities() +169
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Validate() +13
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory() +34
   [namespace].UnitOfWorkProviderNHibernate.InitializeImpl(IDictionary`2 parameters) in C:\path\to\file\UnitOfWorkProviderNHibernate.cs:241
   [namespace].Initialize(IDictionary`2 parameters) in C:\path\to\file\ProviderBase.cs:36
   [namespace].InitializeProvider(ProviderItem providerItem) in C:\path\to\file\BusinessProviderFactory.cs:287
```

**Edit 3:**

I tried to see what the generated `hbm.xml` file looks like to compare it with the one we are using now, that I know it works, and this are my findings:

- In the component tag the class attribute is filled in (even though I didn't specify it in my Map class)
- The accessors are `field` and not `field.camelcase-underscore`
- The attribute `insert=true` is missing in `DocumentData` (it is explicitly given in my Map class)

Answer (score 0):

Century!
I think, the main problem here: d.Property(dd => dd.DocumentData
As I can see, this class is private, and unfortunately, NHibernate can't to map it, and create the objects.
Please, change the access modifiers to this object.

Comment: Unfortunately changing the access modifier of the subclass `MyDocument` to `public` does not change the outcome, nor does changing the modifier of the fields `_documentData`, `_name` and `_format`

Comment: So, you also have to add setters to all properties of IDocument

Comment: Or do it in this way

private string name;

public string Name
{
  get { return name; }
}

Comment: The properties on the interface are supposed to not have a setter and I cannot change it. For testing purpose I tried to make all public and add the setter, but I keep getting the same error message.

Comment: Could you provide full message what are you getting?

Comment: I added the stacktrace of the inner exception, see edit 2

Comment: IObject contains other properties, but this are not mapped to the DB

Comment: Yeah, I understood, but if this class is inside one project with another class that maps. You have to ignore it or to add getters and setter to your class. Unfortunately, NHibernate takes all project with all your classes and try to map it. Just try to do all actions with IObject that you were doing with another class for getting from DB